# Symlink in windows XP

Tags: windows, unix

The question is how to make the similar thing like symlink in windows like in *nix. It's really hard to write whole path to the file in console (even using [tab], it's not the way if you need to change language). Adding everything in PATH is tiring too. It'll be great to make a symlink running one command.

Actually I'm looking for console app.

Answer (score 13):

They're called [junctions](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5388706.html)

And if you want a [GUI](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm) to do it for you...

Comment: +1 for good answer, but I don't think there's anything as easy or as good as linking in posix.

Comment: Be sure to check out the comments in the "junctions" article hyperlinked above.  Many respondents disagree that the steps listed in the article relate to true NTFS junctions.  The link from MotoWilliams' response points to a more authorative MSDN treatment.

Answer (score 9):

I used **[subst](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx)** first as it makes the path shorter. To do it but with mounting a virtual disk as [typicalrunt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/90123/12892) said, I used the **[junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)** utility from Sysinternals.

To make a symlink use the command:

```
junction Disk:\path\to\mount\point Disk:\path\to\something\to\mount
```

To delete it use the `-d` switch:

```
junction -d Disk:\path\to\mount\point Disk:\path\to\something\to\mount
```

Answer (score 7):

Back when I was on windows I used to use a hardlink shell extension. Not sure if this is the same one, but give this one a try: [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html).

Comment: Indeed it is a very convivient utility.

Answer (score 4):

As with most things, SysInternals has you covered this time with [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Older question with longer discussion: [How to create symbolic links in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

There's an Open source GUI Tool for [Creating Symlinks in windows](http://www.taranfx.com/create-symlink-in-windows)

Answer (score -1):

You can create junctsymlinksions in windows with `mklink`.

edit: If you use Vista.

Comment: Symlink in windows XP as you see :)