# Can I configure Eclipse / JBoss integration so it does not rely on deploying Jars to the "server/default/deploy" folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, myeclipse

I am using MyEclipse 7.5 with JBoss 4.2.3 GA.
When I define my local development JBoss server in MyEclipse it always wants to deploy jars, wars etc. to the "server/default/deploy" directory.

Unfortunately our JBoss directory structure for production is "server/XYZ/deploy/abc" (driven by a third party).

As a result our Dev JBoss instances are different from our QA/Staging/Production JBoss instances.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to use JBoss but deploy to that specific folder path "server/XYZ/deploy/abc" rather than the default one "server/default/deploy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MyEclipse IDE, you can change deployment location for Project. Just click on Windows->Preferences->Servers->JBoss.

- Select proper Jboss - For eg. JBoss
  5.x, here you have to set Jboss home directory, For eg. 'd:\Jboss5.0GA'.
- In 'Server Name' field if you specify    'default' then project deployment
  directory will be  for    eg.'d:\Jboss5.0GA\server\default\deploy'. 
  As in your case, you may specify any     other 'Server Name', then deployment
  location will get modified    accordingly.

  For eg. if server name is :'XYZ' then
  deployment location:
  'd:\Jboss5.0GA\server\XYZ\deploy'
  .Make sure you have all configuration
  folders (like conf,lib etc ) at 'server\xyz' as in
  'server\default' folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better answer that uses MyEclipse configuration to do exactly what you want, but I wondered if you could use a directory soft-link, like this:

```
ln -s server/XYZ/deploy/abc server/default/deploy
```

to allow applications to work with the production directory as if it were the default?
This only works on Linux, Unix, OS/X; but Windows Vista and later has similar functionality.

Comment: As (bad) luck would have it we're on Windows XP :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can create links by Far Manager.

Alse read this - [Symlink in windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90121/symlink-in-windows-xp)