# Porting Unix code with symlink() function to Windows

Tags: windows, unix, porting, symlink

I'm porting C/C++ code from Unix to Windows that makes use of the symlink() function.

From what I understand, recent Windows file systems have a equivalent of symbolic links.

What would be the best / most portable way replace the symlink() function, so the same code works on both platforms ?

Comment: You can use an NTFS junction even on older Windows, Win2k I believe, possibly even NT4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Windows Vista there's a function to create true symbolic links: [CreateSymbolicLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Note that Junctions as mentioned in the other answers only support directories, and even with the newer feature, windows symbolic links require you to specify whether the target is a directory or a file. So you won't necessarily be able to get a trivial "drop-in replacement" `symlink()` function.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying technology on Windows is called [Junction points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point). The Boost Filesystem Library is cross platform and can make symlinks:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#create_symlink

Comment: @Timo Geusch: Thanks for updating the link to the latest version - I was just on the way when you made your edit.

Answer (score 0):

[Junctions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) seem to be the answer from [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90121/symlink-in-windows-xp) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-windows) .